# What is the best way to remove a layout element

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a progress bar shown as I am loading images with the webclient object asynchronously. Once the images have been downloaded I set the loadingComplete bool property to True in my viewmodel to indicate that the loading process has been completed. Currently I am using this value for an attached property to set focus on a control.

What I want is to collapse the progress bar control and then show the images.

What I want to know is what is the best way to do this and what are the pros and cons of the following methods?

Should I

1) create a LoadingOpacity bool property on viewmodel which I can then set to set opacity of the progress bar to 0.0 (this would be set when loadingComplete is set)?

2) Or Should I create a Converter (IValueConverter) and use the loadingComplete property to convert this to a Visibility.Collapsed value. This way I do not need any extra properties in my view model?

3) Or should I create a collapsed property on the view model and bind that to the visibility property of the progress bar?

4) or is/are there other ways to do this?

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I wouldn't go with the opacity solution because of mouse hit testing. Your transparent element would still be hit-test-visible, however you might want to fade the progress bar when the download is complete, but maybe a storyboard triggered by an event is a better option for that.
2. I personally like value converters, they are simple, terse, descriptive and to the point. **This is also widely accepted as the correct choice.**
3. MVVM Best practices dictate that the view model not be aware of the view. By introducing a `Visibility` type property to your view model, you couple it to the view in some way (albeit minute).
4. Probably :)

Comment: Yep - option 2 for mine, too :)

Comment: Thanks guys. With regards to 3, should the view model be more model/business oriented? What I mean here is by reading properties I can work out what they are used for but if I bring in opacity or visibility, it becomes a lot harder to understand and they will be specific to the view I have (if I swap out the view, then they  might not be used at all).

Comment: In general, the VM should contain properties that more or less mirror ones in your business model. The VM is view-aware, so it might also contain properties that facilitate view operations such as change notifications (the most obvious), properties for representing view state (read-only, edit, add), commanding properties, etc.

Comment: +1 for option 2 but I think you should highlight option 2 as the prefered option.  Whilst it my be your personal preference I think you could state it more strongly as being the correct choice in this scenario.